# Is it possible to rent CPU cycles?

Tags: hosting

I have an application that takes days to process data. Is there a service that would let me run my application on powerful computers?

I'm not running a website or a web service.  This is taking lots and lots of data files, running them through a big custom application, and outputting a result.

It takes days on my PC and it's something that needs to be done every once in a while, but not continuously.

Cost isn't really an issue, in the sense that my company will pay for it, but of course it should be cheaper than buying a big-ass machine ourselves.

Comment: Pst - does anyone else see only 2 answers even though it says there are 3?

Comment: yea I have noticed that recently on several questions

Comment: One of the answers was deleted, that might be part of the reason.

Comment: Yeah I deleted mine because @ryeguy beat me by 29 seconds

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you considered [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)? You pay by the hour for what you use. No more, no less. You could event rent many servers at once to split the work load.

I'm not sure if that meets your requirement of "powerful computers", because they're just average servers, but at least it will give you a pay-as-you-go solution for running the program off of your own computer.

Comment: The Amazon Cloud service (EC2) is really cheap too - I ran a few jobs there and ended up paying around 50 cents. If you can parallelize your jobs, they have multicore machines for rent as well.

Comment: For people finding this question in 2021 - You can use AWS EC2 instances, which are AWS's excess capacity, and they are even cheaper, per CPU hour.   However, the Spot instances can be terminated (when AWS gets a higher bid for the instance), and you need to handle that in your application, or the application already needs some checkpointing logic or something similar to handle the "killed when partially done" case.   please check this AWS blog post:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/best-practices-for-handling-ec2-spot-instance-interruptions/

Answer (score 4):

Amazon's EC2 Service is an excellent solution for your needs.  You only pay for the time you use, and you can scale up to as many machines as you need.

From their [information](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/):

> Elastic – Amazon EC2 enables you to increase or decrease capacity within minutes, not hours or days. You can commission one, hundreds or even thousands of server instances simultaneously. Of course, because this is all controlled with web service APIs, your application can automatically scale itself up and down depending on its needs.
>
> Flexible – You have the choice of multiple instance types, operating systems, and software packages. Amazon EC2 allows you to select a configuration of memory, CPU, and instance storage that is optimal for your choice of operating system and application. For example, your choice of operating systems includes numerous Linux distributions, Microsoft Windows Server and OpenSolaris.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is not parallel, you won't get many advantages by running it in a "big machine", unless the bottleneck is in the virtual memory swapping. Even the Top500 supercomputers are not essentially faster than any PC for sequential workloads.

If your application can exploit parallelism maybe you could use your company's existent resources more efficiently than just deploying it in one and only pc. If you have a few dozens of computers, you could set up a loosely coupled heterogeneous cluster (or local grid, terminology changes with fashion).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend CPUsage.

It is a "startup" in grid computing.
It's speciality is that any individual can join to the grid with spare cpu cycles. That makes the grid management cheap, thus the grid usage prices are also very cheap.
They have an API which if you integrate into your program, it will be able to run on the system.